# Commit new changes to merged pull request on GitHub

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

Is the following possible: commit to a merged pull request on GitHub?

Comment: Tell us more what you are trying to achieve, please. What is you scenario?

Comment: I created a pull request to a repository. pull request got accepted and merged. After the merge someone comment a nice feature request. I added the new feature and commit it to my fork. Now it does not show up at the pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It is not possible, any pull request is supposed to be reviewed before merging, if you were able to add other changes to a merged pull request it wouldn't be right. So if you have something new to offer you have to create a new pull request.

Comment: Thanks, will create a new pull request.